# Setting custom style on WinUI3

Tags: winui-3

The idea is for a [navigation item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem?view=winrt-22621) to have a full "accented" style when selected.

[image]

I have this one into the XAML:

```
<NavigationView.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem" x:Key="sx1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AccentTextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextOnAccentFillColorPrimaryBrush}"/>
 </Style>
```

Now when I want the "st1" applied to a navigation item:

```
winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Style st0_def(nullptr);
auto st1_def = (Style&)navView.Resources().Lookup(box_value(L"sx1"));
navViewq.FindName(L"item1").as<NavigationViewItem>().Style(st0_def);
navViewq.FindName(L"item2").as<NavigationViewItem>().Style(st1_def);
```

This works, as long as the mouse is **not** over the navigation item. Can I make it so it also works when the mouse is over it and/or pressed over it?

Best,

Comment: Did you mean these [NavigationViewItem](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4cbade6959cda4fca42a299fb540adc2f99c1e8a/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView.xaml#L540) resources or [the applied style](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4cbade6959cda4fca42a299fb540adc2f99c1e8a/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView_v1.xaml#L554)?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I think the applied style; I got the generic.xaml from the app sdk installation anyway.  Basically, I want to replace that accented line that appears when a item is selected with a full background draw of the same color (and the text color accordingly).

Comment: It could be NavigationViewItem*Foreground/Background*Pressed and NavigationViewItem*Foreground/Background*PointerOver.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT hm, can I put them into my style definition as above or must I copy the entire style?

Comment: You can try to put them into your style definition.